# How to display a word document using fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

HTML code

```
<div class='case'>
    <a href="http://localhost/DXXX/case/reqirement.doc" rel="case"> view</a>
</div>
```

Jquery code

```
$(".case").live('click', function(){
    $.fancybox({
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic'
    });
});
```

it's displays the requested content cannot be loaded please try again later.... And I get a download of that document file... How can I display the document file using fancybox

Comment: Generally, Word files do not automatically display in a browser.  It is not a supported web format.

Comment: Is not possible to display in fancybox?

Comment: Not possible to display in fancybox or in the browser in general.

Comment: @Orbling is right, .doc is actually a collection structured XML documents which needs a proper document reader to open

Comment: If you can't open it by itself in a browser, then the plugin is not going to do any better.

Comment: Hmm so I should first display the contents in browser and later display them

Comment: @dude: Word documents and browsers do not mix, the only option open really is to offer such a file for download.  IE in certain environments may offer to open such a file in the browser window, but only when Word is installed, and Word is running within IE in that case.  Generally, it is not achievable.  Supply PDFs instead where appropriate, which still requires a plug-in, but is a good deal more supported across platforms and browsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. Browsers don't have any built-in way to view Word docs so unless the user has configured their browser to open it with some plugin (which 99% of the world hasn't done), the browser will prompt them to download the file.

Answer (score 32):

**UPDATE: Jan 29, 2017**

Google Docs Viewer allows the Word document to be seen as a (read-only) document rather than an image (as it was previously working), so you can actually select and copy from the displayed document into another document.

Added a **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/picssel/vfu581c2/)** using Fancybox v2.1.5

---

The only possible way to do it without all the issues mentioned above is to use Google docs viewer to display the image of the file via iframe ...so this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".word").fancybox({
  'width': 600, // or whatever
  'height': 320,
  'type': 'iframe'
 });
}); //  ready
```

with this html:

```
<a class="word" href="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://domain.com/path/docFile.doc&embedded=true">open a word document in fancybox</a>
```

... should do the trick.

<strike>Just notice that you are not actually opening a Word document but an image of it, which will work if what you want is to show the content of the document only.</strike>

BTW, I noticed that you must be using fancybox v2.x. In that case you don't need the `.live()` method at all since fancyBox v2 already uses "live" to handle clicks.

Comment: @Aamir it means that the path to (or the document name) the document is incorrect

Comment: By the way, if anyone is trying using .net and are trying to display a file from localhost (like I was) the above won't work unless you use a tool that publishes your localhost server as a public url. I used Finch and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Aamir : added a jsfiddle to the answer for demo purposes

Comment: is it possible to open the file in the browser without deploying word file in the server?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you will need some sort of plugin that will know how to handle that MIME type. Other than that it is not possible.

Same goes for any file type...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, short and sweet (with Fancybox latest version) -

```
$.fancybox.open({
            padding: 0,
            href: $url,
            type: 'iframe',
        });
```

Where your $url can be something like -

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<url for your file>&embedded=true
```