# how to display word document in browser in localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I got this code from stackoverflow which can display the word document in browser..   Can it be possible to display the word document in localhost only .. bcz after trying this code .. It's only showing me "no preview available" ..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".word").fancybox({
'width': 600, // or whatever
'height': 320,
'type': 'iframe'
});
}); 

<a class="word" href="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://domain.com/path/docFile.doc&embedded=true">open a word document in fancybox</a>
```

My Piece

```
$path="resume/".$row['resume']; 
echo "<br /><a class='word' href='http://docs.google.com/gview?url=".$path."&embedded=true'>View Resume</a>";
```

M i giving the path incorrectly ?

Comment: is it `$path = http://domain.com/path/docFile.doc` ?? `echo $path` chk the result

Comment: is it working fine? `http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://domain.com/path/docFile.doc&embedded=true` if u hit on browser

Comment: no .. it's only showing no preview available

Comment: hit this url: http://domain.com/path/docFile.doc in browser, working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105329/discussion-between-devpro-and-stilllearning).

Comment: go to domain.com/path/ location and check either doFile.doc available or not

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Browsers don't have any built-in way to view Word docs so unless the user has configured their browser to open it with some plugin (which 99% of the world hasn't done), the browser will prompt them to download the file.

So no browsers currently have the code necessary to render Word Documents, and as far as I know, there are no client-side libraries that currently exist for rendering them either.

you can use Google Documents' Viewer via an

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

You can check solution at [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418850/how-to-display-a-word-document-using-fancybox)

IN case if you wants to open file using download script then you can use the

> Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="document.doc"');
readfile('path-to-file.docx');
?>
```

You can use the office live apps viewer , internet connection is required: `//view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=your_url_here`

put this url in an iframe

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc' width='1366px' height='623px' frameborder='0'>This is an embedded <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.</iframe>
```

If you only wants to display the content then you can convert word file to pdf file type. You can use [cloud convert](http://studentduniya.in/convert-files-one-format-another-easily-using-cloudconvert/) to convert files from one format to another. Currently cloud convert supports upto 128 different file formats.

There is another [SO link for file format conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: what is your exact requirement. Do you wants to only see or edit that document too?

Comment: i just want to view the word document in browser.. i m trying to do it on localhost first

Comment: just edited my answer. please check once for view.officeapps.live.com

Comment: but this code is downloading my word file.. can we just convert the ms word to text document and show it on browser.. i mean its not necessary to show only in ms word..

Comment: If you only wants to display the content then you can convert word file to pdf or any other file format. just edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

The `$path` has to be a full external path so that google docs can access it. You cant use a relative path like you are for this. The document will have to be internet facing to use this code.