# How can I render word document using Bootstrap and Java Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I render a Word document using Bootstrap and Java Script.  I tried all possible ways, but I don't know whether it is possible or not.

I wanted structure like this

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's ckeditor, http://nightly.ckeditor.com/17-09-16-06-04/full/samples/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display a Word document, you could use a workaround as it is described here e.g.

As pointet out in other questions, it is not possible (excluding some exceptions, e.g. as having a plugin installed and configured to open a Word file) to display a Word file in the browser.

Possible ways to get what you want to do are:

- Convert or letting convert the Word file to a PDF and display it
- Using Google Document to display your Word file in an iframe (provided by Google Document functionality)

There are probably better answer to your question if it would be clearer what you want to achieve.

[how to display word document in browser in localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788746/how-to-display-word-document-in-browser-in-localhost)

[How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)

Comment: @torazaburo Thank you for letting me know. Hence I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @ Lawrence Cherone , @Andreas every one i got the solution sorry for late response...