# How to open Microsoft office documents online?

Tags: javascript, php, html, office365, office-js

Where is the problem, tried with many file extension none of them working.

```
echo "<a href='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://myURL"' target='_blank'><i class=\"fa fa-eye fa-1x\" aria-hidden=\"true\"> </i></a>";
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default browser doesn't have any built-in support for doc and ppt files but you can try this solution for just viewing the file

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9421243/8378453

Answer (score 0):

try using OneDrive's embed feature

See answer here: [Embed a Powerpoint in a Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101080/embed-a-powerpoint-in-a-web-page)

(Sorry, Not enough rep to reply to original post)